# Apple MDM Server（APNs）: Certificate Signature Verification failed

Tags: java

I want to create a MDM server to manage my iOS devices. I have enrolled in iOS Apple Developer Program. I have creat a CSR file，and upload it to create Certificate in Apple Push Certificates Portal.But it display the error message:Certificate Signature Verification failed.
I really don't understand what went wrong.

Hope that it can create a certificate successfully.